# Average using a difference from MAX in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to average a column of numbers, throwing out values a specific difference from MAX. The users will not be Excel experts, so I am trying to stay away from Array formulas so they can edit the difference number based on different conditions.

```
=AVERAGEIF(DM7:DM34,"=>Max(DM7:DM34)-3",DM7:DM34)
```

This returns a #Div/0, while the MAX portion alone returns the value I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you may require is something like:

```
=AVERAGEIF(DM7:DM34,">="&MAX(DM7:DM34)-3)
```

You might achieve some added "comfort" by changing `3` in `-3` to a cell reference where the difference number would be placed/changed.

Comment: Thank you, It worked perfectly. What function does the ampersand play? I have used it to concatenate.

Comment: Consider that, in your original, the MAX formula was encapsulated in quotes. That tells excel "treat this like text" and no calculation is done. Pnuts is concatenating the text part (">=") to the formula, which runs as expected. Make sense?